# Why isn't my script responding to class changes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have been using jQuery for some time and this one's stumping me- I really hope I'm just brain-farting!
I have the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.thumb,.link').click(loadContent);

});

function loadContent() {
    alert(this.id);  
 if(this.id == 'contact')  
 {  
   $('#thumbs').hide();  
   $('#content').show().load('contact.html');

   $('#home').addClass('link');  
   $('#contact').removeClass('link');  
 }  
 else if(this.id == 'home')  
 {  
   $('#thumbs').show();  
   $('.thumb').removeClass('dim');  
   $('#content').hide();  
   $('#home').removeClass('link');  
 }  
 else  
 {  
   var projectNumber = parseInt($(this).attr('src').replace("graphics/",""));

   $('#thumbs').hide();  
   $('.thumb').removeClass('dim');  
   $('#content').show().load("projects/" + projectNumber + ".html");  
   $('#home').addClass('link');  
 }  
}
```

and the following HTML:

> ```
> <div id="container">  
> <table id="left"><tr><td><span id="home">SOME GUY</span><br />  
> <span id="all">&gt;</span>&nbsp;<span class="cat">ALL PROJECTS</span><br />
> <span id="furniture">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<span class="cat">FURNITURE</span><br />
> <span id="objects">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<span class="cat">OBJECTS</span><br />
> <span id="graphics">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<span class="cat">GRAPHICS</span><br />
> <span id="web">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<span class="cat">WEB</span><br />
> <span id="contact" class="link">CONTACT</span></td></tr>
> </table>
> <div id="center">
> <div id="thumbs"><img class="thumb furniture" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb web" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb objects" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb web" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb furniture" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb web" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb graphics" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb" src="graphics/0.png" /><img class="thumb web" src="graphics/0.png" /></div>
> <div id="content"></div>
> </div>
> </div>
> ```

The idea is that the "home" link (span id="home") is clicked, the class "link" gets added, making it clickable according to the document.ready function. I can see the class being added, indeed its CSS makes the cursor a pointer so I know it's working. But the loadContent() function seems not to run- it's supposed to alert its ID when clicked and then show the hidden "thumbs" div-- and none of that happens.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.thumb,.link').click(loadContent);
```

Should be:

```
$('.thumb,.link').live('click', loadContent);
```

When the `link` class is added dynamically after the page loads, you need to tell jQuery to look for future instances of it.

Answer (score 1):

`link` class isn't there when `$(document).ready` is executed. Try [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) with 'click' parameter instead of 'click' call.

Comment: Just to add some detail here, this is what binding deals with. Knowing how binding works will help you understand jquery that much more.